# Form: How to properly connect Live Preview with controller? (AngularJS)

Tags: forms, angularjs

Like everyone else who has asked this question about Angular JS, my problem goes deeper than the simple "how to fix blank option in drop down menu". Basically, I am creating a live preview WITH the form that I am creating. Here is what I mean:

The initial blockquote in the HTML is basically the actual reviews that will be there. The second blockquote is the actual LIVE preview. Finally, the third part is the piece of dilemma I am having.

**DILEMMA:**
Here is the dilemma I am having:

By removing: ***ng-model="review.stars"*** from the select tag, my page will load the 5 stars as expected. However, since I need to bind the ratings already posted up, the live preview AND the initial selection of 5 stars, I have to use *ng-model="review.stars"* to bind everything together.

BUT, now what happens is that by adding ***ng-controller=starsController*** along with the ng-model, the whole thing simply doesn't work. I have tried using a few formulas (and one of those was looking promising, one using an *orderProp*), but because I NEED to bind the three aforementioned things, it breaks the code and that specific piece.

I can still select an option from the list, but the preview fails to show it. Furthermore, it will NOT automatically show up the 5th star in the drop down (I have to manually select it).

In case you would like a visual aid to understand better what I'm explaining, let me post a picture of the two situations I am referring to. [This is the image via a link - I don't have enough rep to post it directly here :/](http://postimg.org/image/929by41w9/)

**HTML**

```
<blockquote ng-repeat="review in product.reviews">
            <b>Stars: {{review.stars}}</b>
            {{review.body}}
            <cite>by:  {{review.author}}</cite>
        </blockquote>

        <form name="reviewForm">

        <blockquote>
            <b> Stars: {{review.stars}}</b>
            <br/>
            <b> Review: {{review.body}}</b>
            <br/>
            <cite>by: {{review.author}}</cite>
        </blockquote>


            <select ng-model="review.stars" ng-controller="starsController" name="stars" id="stars">

                <option style="display:none" value=""></option>                          
                <optgroup label="Rate the product">
                   <option value="1 star" name="1 star">1 star</option>
                   <option value="2 stars" name="2 stars">2 stars</option>
                   <option value="3 stars" name="3 stars">3 stars</option>
                   <option value="4 stars" name="4 stars">4 stars</option>
                   <option value="5 stars" name="5 stars" selected="selected">5 stars
                   </option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
            <br/>
```

**JS**

```
 app.controller('starsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.options = [
        { name: '1 star', value: '1 star' }, 
        { name: '2 stars', value: '2 stars' }, 
        { name: '3 stars', value: '3 stars' },
        { name: '4 stars', value: '4 stars' },
        { name: '5 stars', value: '5 stars' }

      ];

      $scope.orderProp = options[4];


}]);
```

Comment: Can you post a plunker? I suspect it may have something to do with the optgroup in your <select>

Comment: Sure. http://embed.plnkr.co/FGSx4lIv339VTV5MCecg/preview

Comment: Ah, I know what the issue is. Your scripts aren't included. If you add the scripts, it should fix part of the issue anyway.

Comment: @pixelbits yes they are included, in the body, however. I now included them in the header. This fixed one problem, but now I still have the dreaded problem I have been trying to fix since day one - a blank option for choice one.

Comment: Could you fix the script tags in the plunker - once its somewhat working I can have a look?

Comment: @pixelbits I did 10 minutes ago. Did it not show on your side? EDIT: weird, it reverted back after I saved it. Should work as intended - the plunker that is.

Comment: there seems to be more things wrong with the plunker that is not stated in your post. A more focused plunker would be helpful - only include the bare minimum bits to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Should work with the bare minimum now: http://embed.plnkr.co/FGSx4lIv339VTV5MCecg/preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5GyEXjXDAiJt3DNvXtf3?p=preview)

To fix this, add ng-init="review={}" to your form tag.

```
<form name="reviewForm" ng-init="review={}">
```

Or, even better - move ng-controller higher up the DOM tree (maybe on your form element)

```
<form name="reviewForm" ng-controller="starsController">
```

Or the best option, create a custom reviewStars directive:

```
app.directive('reviewStars', function() {...});
```

Comment: I am trying with the directive function, but I find the documentation to be terrible (like if they explain half of what readers wants to know). Anyhow, I know my new plunker for the directive is terrible, but I gave it a shot anyhow lol. http://embed.plnkr.co/2FiNhxCcu6MrK8pxo0Cg/preview

Comment: I wish all tutorials were as simple as following yours. I toyed around with the coding you showed me (30 minutes or so), and I was able to integrate it flawlessly afterwards. I would up the answer, but I don't have enough reps unfortunately. Kudos!